# Good freeware clone of the VMS editor EDT for unix or the pc?

Tags: unix, editor, vms, edt

I would like to have the same editor available on all of the platforms I frequent.

Emacs and Vi are not desired solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/edt-text-editor/

Answer (score 1):

There is [nu/TPU](http://www.asoft-dev.com/) which is more like EVE/TPU, and also [JED](http://www.jedsoft.org/jed/), I've never found anything better than either of these.

I used to be the world's biggest fan of VMS and EVE/EDT/TPU - you're probably going to -1 me for saying this but why not [get edt mode for emacs](http://www.bmen.tulane.edu/~rthart/EDTdescription.html). There is a lot to be said for emacs in terms of speed and facilities and it is worth taking the time to learn enough to turn it into your editor of choice, which I think is why us folks who like emacs like it - because we can customise it to do what we want...

Currently I'm using Xemacs - customised to my keystrokes some of which came from EDT.

Comment: One of the best things with TPU was the programming language, and I suppose that even if EDT mode in emacs can imitate the key bindings, you would still have to write Lisp if you want to extend it...